# Gitlab password reset in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

I'm trying to login to the web panel of my forgotten gitlab install but somehow the password is not working. I have tried to reset it in the console by the following

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rails console production
user = User.where(email: 'myemail@mail.com').first
user.password = 'password'
user.save
```

and i can confirm that a new encrypted password was set in the user table of the database, but still i cannot log in.

Using gitlab 6 on ubuntu.

What else could i do to reset the password or find out why i cant login.

Comment: try `user.save!` (with a bang) and see if it raises an exception. `user.save` just returns `false` if the saving fails.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the password confirmation too:

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'admin@local.host')
user.password = 'secret_pass'
user.password_confirmation = 'secret_pass'
user.save!
```

(Exclamation point is important)

Answer (score 0):

As [Philipp Antar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088092/philipp-antar) pointed out, you have to use `user.save!` to persist the record in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Environment: Gitlab Omnibus installed on Debian Jessie (SmartOS LX image)

I would have preferred to say this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation (after many years of being a ghost on the internet I'm starting to talk)...

I found this thread while trying to deal with this issue (I had installed Gitlab, played with it for a few days, and then moved on to installing other things and forgotten the credentials for my user account)(I had also forgotten that there was a 'root' account). My initial searching led me to basically these same instructions (Gitlab official docs for resetting root password: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_root_password.html ). 
Using them I was immediately able to reset the password for the root account and login but when I performed the same steps to access my (non-root) user account it didn't work. I performed the steps three times (it's hard to miss an exclamation point when copy/pasting and I could scroll up in the console and SEE that I did it correctly, but I always want to be sure).
In the end I reset the gitlab machine and the new password for my user account then worked. For anyone who has tried this and had it not work, I suggest a reset.